# Converting existing web app to use hashtag URIs using Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm attempting to use Backbone and it's Router to turn an app into an ajax app, however it currently uses several different methods (helpers) of generating links. Unfortunately, this means manually changing each and every link to use a hashtag is out of the question.

What would be the best method of ensuring every link, form post, redirect, etc. gets parsed as a hashtag URL that can be caught by Backbone's Router? Or, even better, is it possible for the Router to accept "true URL's" from a request? Example: a request to /app/mail/inbox.php is caught by a rule in the Router, and is turned into #/mail/inbox after firing the appropriate method to handle the request.

Comment: So you want to catch the anchor `onclick`, convert the URL, and issue a window.location.hash instead?  That would work, if your client-side mapper is smart enough.  It would completely make your site SEO blind, but it would work.

Comment: Not just anchor clicks though, also form submits, redirects, or just a normal GET request. Also, not worried about SEO. Users have to login to this portion of the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What would be the best method of ensuring every link, form post, redirect, etc. gets parsed as a hashtag URL that can be caught by Backbone's Router?

I don't think that `Backbone.Router` is supposed to handle, say, form posts. It's supposed to give your application *view state*—bookmark-friendly and refreshable URLs [1].

If you want to ‘ajaxify’ forms, then you probably should add a handler for form's submit event and do something like `$.ajax()` there, preventing the default action.

Regarding plain old links, [`History.pushState()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History) support has been added to Backbone recently. It means that you can define your routes as `/app/*`, and don't need to replace old `href` attributes. However, you'll still need to catch link click events to prevent default action.

For example:

```
var handle_link_click = function(e) {
    path = $(e.target).attr('href');
    app.main_router.navigate(path, true); // This.
    e.preventDefault();
};
$('a:internal').click(handle_link_click);
```

Router's [`navigate()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate) method will do `history.pushState()` if it's available, falling back to old `hashchange`. And `true` as a second argument means that it will fire corresponding handler action.

[1] See also [this presentation about Backbone](http://backbone-dot-js-intro.heroku.com/)

Comment: This is just the information I was looking for. I'm a bit concerned about supporting both pushState and hashtag URLs, since pushState isn't quite supported by the versions of IE that I need to support. Even with that drawback, I still think this is the most viable option. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by drawback: maybe I was a bit unclear about it in the answer, but, as far as I can tell, before calling corresponding handler function, `router.navigate()`  *does* fire hashchange event (`#/app/*`) if `history.pushState(/app/*)` is not available. So you get older browser support: IE6 will just use hashtags, and handler functions still will be called.

Comment: Gotcha, that was my misunderstanding. Thanks for clarifying.